# Selected attribute doesn't work unless it is the last item in the array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form where I want to have a default selected item based on certain criteria. I have an array (myList) with items used to populate the select list and a variable (myItem) that comes from a backend api and I want my selected value to be myItem but this only works if myItem is the last item in the array.

So this would not work (no default selected item)

```
this.myList = ['Dave', 'Jerry', 'Sam']
this.myItem = 'Jerry'

<*ngFor="let list of myList" [ngValue]="list" [selected]="list === myItem">{{list}}</option> 

but this would work

this.myList = ['Dave', 'Jerry', 'Sam']
this.myItem = 'Sam'

<*ngFor="let list of myList" [ngValue]="list" [selected]="list === myItem">{{list}}</option>
```

I would be glad if someone tells my why this happens.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `myItem` be a string, not an array?

Comment: @KurtHamilton thanks for the correction. I have edited my post.

Comment: I recommend you to don’t use formGroups just form and to develop your own custom directives for validations in the case that you need another that the basics. That way you could use the ngModel and clean the code of your .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the same approach to binding `<select>` elements as you do `<input>` elements. If you bind `<input>` elements using ngModel, then your select should look a little like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="myItem" ... other attributes ...>
  <option *ngFor="let option of myList">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ngModel is deprecated in reactive form in Angular 6 and I am using Angular 8.
Thanks

Comment: Ah, it would have helped if you stated that in the question. In that case use the same approach for your reactive form `<select>` and you fo your reactive form `<input>` - by using formControl or formControlName directives on the select rather than setting the selected attribute on the options.